# Why is the <i> in the title to question 26789031 causing the formatting of the other questions to be italicized?

Tags: discussion, bug

Question 26789031 has `<i>` in its title. For some reason, looking at the question list filtered by the `[javascript]` tag, the subsequent questions are all in italics.

I tried editing out the `<i>` and the problem went away; it's back in now (as I type this at least).

Here is the post link: [Changing text dynamically, how to not remove the <i> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789031)

*edit* I at first thought that the `<i>` was being emitted somehow, but before I even got Firebug up I realized that probably wasn't the case. What *does* seem to be happening (it may be fixed already) is that subsequent questions are getting wrapped in `<i>` tags. That leaves me completely flummoxed but since I have absolutely no insight into the way the site works that's not surprising.

Like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ8lL.png]

*edit again* — please note that this was not intended as a stunt; I didn't think it'd leak into MSO.

Comment: I see it too on Chrome/Win7.

Comment: @Joe It's on the [javascript question list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: This also repro's on Win7/IE11

Comment: Whatever you did has made the list of questions on MSO italicized.

Comment: @bluefeet well to be fair I did not come up with this brilliant hack :)

Comment: @Pointy Maybe brilliant, but incredibly annoying to look at.

Comment: [Oh god what's going on???](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Msmu1.jpg)

Comment: @gunr2171 That's from the code block in the [question above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789299/using-angular-1-3-ngmessage-for-form-submission-errors), probably related to the other layout reports popping up

Comment: MSO front page never looked better. Keep it on! Wonder what happens if title gets `<b>`. Or if title gets `<i> along with closing </i>`...

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't look that bad in italics. Sort of like a Fancy StackOverflow (o_Q) ah well it was interesting while it lasted.